# Which Spring module can be used to develop workflow/automation system?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, automation

I have a developed a web-based application using springBoot and AngularJs.In this project, action is taken by the user(checker) based on inputs provided by the maker.

Now I want to develop a workflow/automation system, which will automate the checker's action, therefore the human intervention of checker will not be required. Workflow/automation system will take the actions by itself. There can be around 3000 workflow scenarios.

Can anyone guide me which Spring Boot framework/module can be used to achieve this?

Comment: What you mean Boot framework, are you looking for Automation framework?

Comment: +Vivek Pakmode, I am asking about Spring Boot framework / module

Comment: Questions asking for a tool, framework etc. are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Activiti which has a spring module that might solve your problem.
http://www.baeldung.com/spring-activiti

Not really enough details to know for sure if it will work for you.

For something external to your app and more capable (and heavier) that you could call with APIs check jBPM. 
https://www.jbpm.org/

Comment: This set of Activiti articles might be of use - https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/wiki/Articles-and-Blogs-on-Activiti It sounds like you'd be looking to embed activiti in a spring boot app. Note that the activiti6 kickstart app is an alternative where activiti runs standalone and you embed any logic you want into it (much as Joe W suggests with jBPM). If you're looking for a longer discussion you could have a look at Activiti in Action.

Comment: As for another similar question, I suggest [Camunda](https://camunda.com/). It's a fork of Activiti, has much more features and, if you trust the developers, is more fast and robust.

Answer (score 1):

When developing a workflow/automation system with Spring, you can utilize the Spring State Machine module. Spring State Machine provides a framework for creating and managing state-driven workflows. It allows you to define states, events, and transitions, and handle actions and decisions based on those transitions.

While Spring State Machine is a viable option for workflow development, I'd also like to mention Klamp.io, a powerful workflow automation tool. [Klamp.io](https://klamp.io) offers seamless integration, customizable workflows, and process optimization, enabling you to build and automate complex workflows efficiently. It provides a user-friendly interface and extensive features for developing and managing workflow systems. Consider exploring Klamp.io to simplify your workflow automation requirements.